# How can I ignore missing data points (no value for a key) on an Apache Zeppelin line chart?

Tags: graph, charts, linechart, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to plot a basic line chart in Zeppelin fitting multiple groups to a single key set (number of results per group per day). However, for certain days there may or may not be data, as shown:

[image: A chart showing three trend lines for the last week of September. One trend line has data for every day on the chart; the two others have no data for one or two days. Instead of bypassing the days for which no data exist, these lines display a value of zero on those days, causing dips and recoveries that give the appearance of anomalous data.]

None of the records have a key field of 09/25 so that date doesn't even appear. Light blue and orange have no data for 09/26; light blue has no data for 09/29. But since dark blue has data for 09/26, Zeppelin "accommodates" the missing data for light blue and orange by zeroing them out for that day (it does the same for `null` values in other charts so I expect that that isn't the answer). This is undesirable since it appears that we *have* data for those days, and that there were simply no results. I'm looking for a way to ignore those keys when no records correspond, similar to how Excel's `#N/A` behaves -- so the orange line would travel directly from 09/24 to 09/27 instead of having the sharp dip and recovery. How do I do this?

Comment: Digging into it further: this seems to be happening in the visualization, where the built-in line chart is invoking `d3DataFromPivot` with `fillMissingValues` toggled on. It doesn't look like this is directly configurable. Time to look into adding a new visualization with that switched off, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hardcoded behavior issue with line charts and has been fixed in the 0.8.0 snapshot as [ZEPPELIN-2252](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2252).